# Problem with upload image from android(retrofit) to django

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I would like to send a photo from android app to django. I use django rest framework as backend.

When i post through postman everything works and I get 201. But when i try through android, I get 400. Where is the problem? Thanks for help in advance

My model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
```

My django view:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
        file_serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Retrofit request:

```
    @Headers("content-type: multipart/form-data;")
    @POST("upload")
    fun checkItem(@Body image: MultipartBody.Part): Observable<CheckDto>
```

That's how i send my photo from android app:

```
        val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)
        val body: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.toString(), requestFile)

        val requestInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        myCompositeDisposable?.add(requestInterface.checkItem(body)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({ result ->
                Log.d("Request", result.toString())
            }, { error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
            })
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) because of the data you're trying to send. Your server accepts `multipart/form-data` whereas you're sending serialized object from Android.

You might ask now that how it's even possible?

Well, when you use Retrofit's [`@Body`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html) annotation, the object will be serialized using the Retrofit instance Converter and the result will be set directly as the request body.

So, what's the solution?

Just replace your code from

```
@Headers("content-type: multipart/form-data;")
@POST("upload")
fun checkItem(@Body image: MultipartBody.Part): Observable<CheckDto>
```

to

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
fun checkItem(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part): Observable<CheckDto>
```

1. Remove `@Headers()` annotation and use [`@Multipart`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Multipart.html) as we're sending `multipart/form-data`.
2. Replace `@Body` with [`@Part`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Part.html)

That's it!